# How to merge two or more coffeescript files together with duplicate function names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, merge, coffeescript

I'm trying to merge all my coffeescript files together on my rails 3.1 asset pipeline website so the development pages can load faster. I'm down to 6 seconds from 28 seconds. But the formerly unique local function names are now all in the same file and bumping into duplicates. I'd like to maintain the same function names but within some kind of namespace.

Here are a couple sample files.

File a.js.coffee

```
root = exports ? this

$(document).ready -> 
  sayHi()

root.sayHi = ->
  greeting()

greeting = ->
  alert("Howdy")
```

File b.js.coffee

```
root = exports ? this

$(document).ready -> 
  sayHello()

root.sayHello = ->
  greeting()

greeting = ->
  alert("Hi there")
```

How can I join the contents of these two files together and still keep the two separate `greeting` functions?

new file ab.js.coffee

```
#------------------
# from a.js.coffee
#------------------

root = exports ? this

$(document).ready -> 
  sayHi()

root.sayHi = ->
  greeting()

greeting = ->
  alert("Howdy")

#------------------
# from b.js.coffee
#------------------

root = exports ? this

$(document).ready -> 
  sayHello()

root.sayHello = ->
  greeting()

greeting = ->
  alert("Hi there")
```

Comment: What are you using to join the files? By default coffee wraps each file in an IIFE (`(function(){ ...)()`) to avoid those clashes.

Comment: I am physically copying the contents of each of the individual coffeescript files into one big file. The Rails server on my development machine is taking way too long to render a page with each file individually. Before the merging it took 28 secs to finish one page, after the merge it only takes 4 secs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to namespace the functions is to just use objects.

```
#------------------
# from a.js.coffee
#------------------

a = 
  sayHi: ->
    @greeting

  greeting: ->
    console.log('a')
    alert("Howdy")

#------------------
# from b.js.coffee
#------------------

b = 
  sayHello: ->
    @greeting

  greeting: ->
    console.log('b')
    alert("Hi there")


#------------------
# initializer
#------------------

$(document).ready -> 
  a.sayHi()
  b.sayHello()
  return
```

Comment: I'm going to try this. What is the "@greeting"? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Ah, I see '@' is an alias for 'this'.